# How to consume a webapi in webservice using .net framework 2.0

Tags: web-services, asp.net-web-api, c#-2.0

I need to consume a webapi service which is developed using java. While connecting to the api I am getting error as  "Unable to retrieve resources for ' '".

When I consume the same api through soapUI I am able to get response. 
Am I missing something?

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        client.Headers.Clear();
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/xml";
        client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Accept] = "application/xml";
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(StrRequestXML);
        byte[] result = client.UploadData("url+soapaction", "POST", data);
        string xmlResponse = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
     }
     catch (WebException ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
}
```

Comment: can you capture the message that works with something like fiddler and compare it with the message you craft?

Comment: Its resolved, I have been posting to wrong url. Thanks

Comment: @Swapy please close your question if it was due to a "typo" (wrong url)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
byte[] result = client.UploadData("url+soapaction", "POST", data);
```

you pass string `"url+soapaction"` but there should be The URI of the resource to receive the data.

Maybe you mean

```
byte[] result = client.UploadData(url + soapaction, "POST", data);
```